# Check if an apex list contains an object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Is there any way to check if a list contains a certain element?  I looked at the List functions and did not see any contain() function like Java or C# , so I was wondering how other people are handling this.

I really need to use a List I **cant** use a **Map** like in this example [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Check-if-a-list-contains-an-object/td-p/98131)

What I have now is really bad..

```
                    for  (String s : allContacts)
                    {                      

                      for(String ic:insertedContacts)
                        {                          
                            if (s != ic )
                            {
                                     errorContacts.add(s);
                                     break;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                 }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A Set might be what you're looking for.

1. Define a new Set. `Set<String> mySet = new Set<String>();`
2. Use the [`Set.addAll()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_set.htm) method to add all of the List elements to the set. `mySet.addAll(myList);`.
3. Use the [`Set.contains()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_methods_system_set.htm) method to check the Set for the element you're looking for.

Comment: Sometimes I am driven mad by salesforce. I need to store a list of unique key value pairs. First I wanted to use lists but I did not want to iterate through all elements to prevent inserting a duplicate key value. I thought of using maps since they have a containskey() method to check for duplicates before insertion. I also need to expose this data to visualforce and looks like maps cannot be bound to visualforce elements like apex:repeat.

Comment: salesforce drives me mad too.

Comment: `<apex:repeat>` can be used to iterate over a map, too. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9323/72

Comment: @MattK yes, but only in visualforce, the question is related to Apex code.